# Is the GPS linked to WiFi connection in Android?

Tags: android

I have written a code that detects my current location. But it locates only if my WiFi connection is OnAm not switching On the GPS manually as i have enabled it programatically.
 And if i enable GPS manually, it is not locating my position.. Is the GPS and WiFi linked in Android.?  Can any one help me out from this and tell me what may be the reason for such thing to happen..Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple Location providers in Android. GPS and Network are the two of the most frequently used.

While GPS does not need Wifi, Network provider needs Wifi to give you location.

To answer your question GPS does not need a wifi but a line of sight to give you the new location information.

Comment: First of all i thank you for giving me response. Can I get some sample code where our current position is found only using the GPS.